# Gl React Expo rescaling captured image

Tags: react-native, opengl-es, expo

I have an issue where the output image from a Surface suffers a rescaling, not remaining the same resolution as the original.

Some examples of input and output, along with the render size of the surface.

Example 1:

```
Original Image = {
  height: 2560,
  width: 1440,
}

Final Image = {
  height: 1518,
  width: 854,
}

Surface Size = {
  height: 284.625,
  width: 506
}
```

Example 2:

```
Original Image = {
  height: 357,
  width: 412,
}

Final Image = {
  height: 936,
  width: 1080,
}

Surface Size = {
  height: 360,
  width: 311.9417475728156
}
```

To capture the image, I use the following code:

```
getEditedImage = async () => {
  return await this.image.glView.capture({ quality: 1 });
};
```

where `image` represents the surface from which I'm capturing the image.

I want the output image resolution to be exactly the same as the input. Does someone have an idea how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

you see how to use here.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/gl-view/

The format (string), compressing (number) parts seem to be the part you need.

---

source: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/take-snapshot-async/

This link contains a description of the quality.

## takeSnapshotAsync(view, options)

- quality : number -- Number between 0 and 1 where 0 is worst quality and 1 is best, defaults to 1

```js
const targetPixelCount = 1080; // If you want full HD pictures
const pixelRatio = PixelRatio.get(); // The pixel ratio of the device
// pixels * pixelratio = targetPixelCount, so pixels = targetPixelCount / pixelRatio
const pixels = targetPixelCount / pixelRatio;

const result = await takeSnapshotAsync(this.imageContainer, {
  result: 'file',
  height: pixels,
  width: pixels,
  quality: 1,
  format: 'png',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @samjamy, but this version of the documentation is outdated. The equivalent now is 

    this.image.glView.capture({ quality: 1 });

and there is no compress parameter in this case (and no actual documentation whatsoever).

Comment: @Vinícius Marinho Schnabel Your answer has been updated.

Comment: There's a description of the quality. I think we can use this.